# How to mimic Android Settings App UI design?

Tags: android

I am trying to replicate the Android Settings App UI categories but was unable to do that. Any idea how to add several sections/categories to a View similar to the following? Is this achievable using a LinearLayout? Or is there a different layout component that would give the same effect?

[image]

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: I tried using a LinearLayout that included a TextView and a toggle button, but didn't get the same effect